# Amazon S3 403 error when attempting to PUT with boost asio

Tags: c++, boost, amazon-s3, boost-asio

I'm trying to upload a file to my S3 bucket using the PUT verb with boost asio.

I generated a pre-signed URL with the aws-sdk ruby gem:

```
my_url = Aws::S3::Resource.new.bucket("mybucket").object("file.txt").presigned_url(:put)   
# my_url returns: https://mybucket.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/file.txt?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=MY_ACCESS_KEY_ID%2F20150803%2Fus-west-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20150803T194921Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=a11bdaefc1c4580c0c21bfa889c75e4506de76a59e2e7eeaf7c35e9054daf15f
```

To test this pre-signed URL, I used curl to upload a file(found this command on SO)

`$ curl -v --upload-file file.txt "[URL_FROM_RUBY_CODE]"`

Which returned a 200 OK response, and used the following request headers

```
...

PUT /file.txt?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=MY_ACCESS_KEY_ID%2F20150803%2Fus-west-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20150803T194921Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=a11bdaefc1c4580c0c21bfa889c75e4506de76a59e2e7eeaf7c35e9054daf15f HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
Host: mybucket.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 20
Expect: 100-continue

...

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
```

This curl command worked perfectly, and the file uploaded.
But when I try to use boost asio, I keep getting a `403 Forbidden` error.
Here's my C++ code:

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator iter = resolver.resolve(boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query("mybucket.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com", "80"));
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock(io_service);
boost::asio::connect(sock, iter);

std::string req = "PUT /file.txt?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=MY_ACCESS_KEY_ID%2F20150803%2Fus-west-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20150803T194921Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=a11bdaefc1c4580c0c21bfa889c75e4506de76a59e2e7eeaf7c35e9054daf15f HTTP/1.1\r\n";
req += "Host: mybucket.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com\r\n";
req += "Accept: */*\r\n";
req += "Content-Lenght: 4\r\n";
req += "Expect: 100-continue\r\n\r\n";

req += "TEST";

boost::asio::write(sock, boost::asio::buffer(req.c_str(), req.length()));

char res[2048];
boost::asio::read(sock, boost::asio::buffer(res));
```

I just don't see what I'm doing wrong in the C++ code. Could someone help out?

**EDIT**
Here's the response I'm getting.

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

x-amz-request-id: 1BF06BB2183CF427

x-amz-id-2: JEzslTC9jsKbo2LiUV80rZhaSQpMkWjAcfqztXeR9lTsMrqt/cCPjJwWx/SphfQzqhutaZSq5d0=

Content-Type: application/xml

Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Date: Mon, 03 Aug 2015 23:44:03 GMT

Connection: close

Server: AmazonS3



8de

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>AKIAIDKQLZIT2IIG33SQ</AWSAccessKeyId><StringToSign>AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20150803T234253Z
20150803/us-west-1/s3/aws4_request
f962380b7de26fa6a92c84ea48cde101dcf38c653d01bb03105b8bc45b28fca9</StringToSign><SignatureProvided>6ce83e89e9b2c3322bad92fad584f9cb419273a307930cbce64954093424ddb9</SignatureProvided><StringToSignBytes>41 57 53 34 2d 48 4d 41 43 2d 53 48 41 32 35 36 0a 32 30 31 35 30 38 30 33 54 32 33 34 32 35 33 5a 0a 32 30 31 35 30 38 30 33 2f 75 73 2d 77 65 73 74 2d 31 2f 73 33 2f 61 77 73 34 5f 72 65 71 75 65 73 74 0a 66 39 36 32 33 38 30 62 37 64 65 32 36 66 61 36 61 39 32 63 38 34 65 61 34 38 63 64 65 31 30 31 64 63 66 33 38 63 36 35 33 64 30 31 62 62 30 33 31 30 35 62 38 62 63 34 35 62 32 38 66 63 61 39</StringToSignBytes><CanonicalRequest>PUT
/file.txt
X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&amp;X-Amz-Credential=MY_ACCESS_KEY_ID%2F20150803%2Fus-west-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&amp;X-Amz-Date=20150803T234253Z&amp;X-Amz-Expires=900&amp;X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host
host:mybucket.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com

host
UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD</CanonicalRequest><CanonicalRequestBytes>50 55 54 0a 2f 66 69 6c 65 2e 74 78 74 0a 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 41 6c 67 6f 72 69 74 68 6d 3d 41 57 53 34 2d 48 4d 41 43 2d 53 48 41 32 35 36 26 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 43 72 65 64 65 6e 74 69 61 6c 3d 41 4b 49 41 49 44 4b 51 4c 5a 49 54 32 49 49 47 33 33 53 51 25 32 46 32 30 31 35 30 38 30 33 25 32 46 75 73 2d 77 65 73 74 2d 31 25 32 46 73 33 25 32 46 61 77 73 34 5f 72 65 71 75 65 73 74 26 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 44 61 74 65 3d 32 30 31 35 30 38 30 33 54 32 33ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌøèP
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is at least one thing very obviously wrong: You have misspelled "Content-Length" as "Content-Leng**ht**".

More generally, the request signature is time-dependent; this one would have expired 15 minutes (900 seconds) after the date specified in `X-Amz-Date` - that is, around 20:05 GMT today. If you ran your application after this time, the signature will have expired, so the request would be rejected. Hard-coding a request in your C++ program will not work in general; you will need to have your application generate a signature to have it work over the long term.

Comment: Good catch! Unfortunately I'm still getting 403 errors. I plan to generate the pre-signed URL in response to a user action, and then send it back allowing them to upload files. But for now I've made sure that the URL I'm using to test isn't expired.

Comment: What's in the body of the 403 error, then? There should be a more specific error mentioned there.

Comment: I updated the original post with the response. Also, I'm getting the same response as when I had `Content-Length` spelled incorrectly.

Comment: OK, I don't know what I did, but somehow it's working now.